# Get the table affected by the query

Tags: sql-server, table

How I can get the table which is affected by the query?

Example

```
Update cust
Set name = 'john'
Where custid = '4001'

Output:
cust

___________________________

Insert into emp(fname, lname)
Values('john', 'reyes')

Output:
emp


___________________________


Update cust
Set name = 'john'
Where custid = '4001'
Update emp
Set fname = 'rey'
Where fname = 'John'

Output:
cust, emp
```

Comment: What's your motivation?  Are you profiling hotspots in your DB, or auditing or what?  How do you hope to consume the responses?

Answer (score 0):

For your first example:

```
Update cust
Set name = 'john'
output 'cust'  
--, inserted.Name  -- optionally, uncomment this field as well, to get the Key of the updated record.
Where custid = '4001'
```

Answer (score 0):

A trigger is an option to do this.

```
   create trigger ins_updt_trig 
    on cust 
    for update, insert
    as
    begin
    print 'cust'
    end
```

This will display a message when an update or insert occurs on `'cust'` table. But I don't think this is a better option for a lot of tables because triggers are very difficult to manage.